# Why does this tick box issue happen?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tick boxes that are linked to cells so that i can just use code to set them true or false and instantly control the tick boxes. problem is, when i organize a column in any way (in this case, lowest to highest number), the tick boxes get all mixed up (they switch places with each other). this makes it so when i try to tick a certain number,it'll tick a random number that i don't want to tick.

i don't really know what code i should place here, hope this bit helps

```
If Range("h10").Value >= 0 Then
   Range("bk10").Value = True
Else
   Range("bk10").Value = False
End If
```

(bk10 is supposed to represent specifically the line number 10)

Comment: You need to (1) make sure the checkboxes are not spanning multiple cells (2) set their position to "move but not size with cells".

Comment: Since both branches of the conditional are assigning a Boolean value to the same member expression, consider rewriting it as `Range("BK10").Value = (Range("H10").Value >= 0)` - also consider qualifying these `Range` calls with an explicit `Worksheet` object if that code is written in `ThisWorkbook` or in a standard module, or with the `Me` qualifier if that code is written in a `Worksheet` module. An unqualified `Range` call made in a standard module, userform, or workbook module, will implicitly refer to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is.

Comment: @TimWilliams  it wasn't "move but not size with cells", i had to place "dont move and dont size with cells", but thank you so much for solving the issue.